Pandas: Filter duplicated values into DataFrame and parse them to Excel
I have a Pandas DataFrame with one column with clients names that I use to filter a SQLAlchemy query. Some values in this columns contains duplicated, even triplicated clients. The scope of this script is to create Excel Workbooks for each client, including those with duplicated/triplicated values.
This is what I'm using to query the database:
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    clients = (session.query(Client).filter(Client.name == row['Name']).all())

    for client in clients:
        ...

Actually this work fine, but it generates one file for each client, what I need is: when clients are duplicated or triplicated into the DataFrame, it stores them on the same Workbook and don't overwrite existing Excel files.
I also tried using this to find the duplicated clients:
df.groupby('Name').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2)


did you try df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name']) ?

This will remove the duplicated clients from my DataFrame, what I need it's to make Excel files for each client, including the duplicated ones, but in the same file instead.

Mmh, I don't get everything then, if you then query the database with the 'Name' column it will return exactly the same each time so you don't need to loop through the duplicates, or I misunderstood something ?

I forgot to mention that the duplicates are only into the Name column, others columns have different values from each other, that's why I can't drop them. It's working fine by now using df.groupby(by=["Name"]). Thanks for the help!

If you want a file for each unique client, you could loop over all the unique clients using the groupby method. You can take the table of all rows related to that name and save it to one excel file.
import pandas as pd

# create a dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["A",1,1],["A",2,2],["B",3,3]],
                  columns=["Name","Other", "More"])

# create a DataFrameGroupBy object grouped by the unique names
grouped = df.groupby(by=["Name"])[["Other", "More"]]
# loop over all the groups
for group in grouped:
    # unpack the tuple group to the value for name and the related rows
    name, table = group
    # save the resulting table per client to excel.
    table.to_excel(f"{name[0]}.xlsx")

